# Spring data sort by nested property

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, pagination, spring-data

I am using pagination in spring boot. When getting a page from DB, i want to sort data by a nested property. Here is the code where I create a Page request .

`Pageable pageOfElements = PageRequest.of(pageNumber, pageSize, Sort.by("customDateObject").descending());`

my custom object implements comparable, but sorting does not work, how can I fix this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please post an entity (class) of the object with this particular "customDateObject"?

Answer (score 3):

You can nest properties inside your sort by parameter:

```
Pageable pageOfElements = PageRequest.of(pageNumber, pageSize, Sort.by("customDateObject.customProperty").descending());
```

So for example, if you are sorting `Cars` by the `id` of their `owner`, you would do the following:

```
Sort.by("owner.id")
```